# What is the replacement for undocumeneted Windows Kernel API - KeSetAffinityThread() in Windows 7 and later OS

Tags: kernel, windows-kernel

`void KeSetAffinityThread(PKTHREAD pKThread, KAFFINITY cpuAffinityMask)` routine is available in Windows Kernel and its documentation can be found in OS/2 Kernel docs. And Windows still retains this API in its kernel. This API can be used to set affinity mask of any thread. I am looking for ways to do this when we have more than 64 processors in the system.

Little background -
With the introduction of processor groups feature in Windows 7, we can no longer safely rely on KAFFINITY, thus I cannot use the above API as the code will be unreliable when run on systems with more than 64 processors. I was not able to find appropriate replacement in MSDN, the API's provided by MSDN include `KeSetSystemAffinityThread`, `KeSetSystemGroupAffinityThread` but it doesn't serve my purpose as these calls are only used to set affinity of the calling thread.

I also see a function - `SetThreadAffinityMask()` to set affinity of an arbitrary thread but this is an user level routine. I am looking for something similar in kernel mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [KeSetSystemAffinityThreadEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, `KeSetSystemAffinityThreadEx` can be used only to set affinity of the calling thread. But I want to set affinity of an arbitrary thread.

Answer (score 0):

User mode `SetThreadAffinityMask` API calls `NtSetInformationThread`.
You can do the same in kernel mode:

```cpp
ULONGLONG affinity = <affinity mask>;
ZwSetInformationThread(hThread, ThreadAffinityMask, &affinity, sizeof(affinity));
```